# C++ pass list as a parameter to a function

Tags: c++, list, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm trying to build a very simple address book. I created a Contact class and the address book is a simple list. I'm trying to build a function to allow the user to add contacts to the address book. If I take my code outside of the function, it works OK. However, if I put it in, it doesn't work. I believe it's a passing by reference vs passing by value problem which I'm not treating as I should. This is the code for the function:

```
void add_contact(list<Contact> address_book)
{
     //the local variables to be used to create a new Contact
     string first_name, last_name, tel;

     cout << "Enter the first name of your contact and press enter: ";
     cin >> first_name;
     cout << "Enter the last name of your contact and press enter: ";
     cin >> last_name;
     cout << "Enter the telephone number of your contact and press enter: ";
     cin >> tel;

     address_book.push_back(Contact(first_name, last_name, tel));
}
```

I don't get any errors however when I try to display all contacts, I can see only the original ones.

Comment: The `list<Contact> addressBook ` is not being update when calling `add_contact(addressBook);`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're passing `address_book` by value, so a copy of what you pass in is made and when you leave the scope of `add_contact` your changes are lost.

Pass by reference instead:

```
void add_contact(list<Contact>& address_book)
```

Comment: Is every STL DS is pass by value?

Comment: @Rahul : C++ as a language has [_value semantics_](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/value-vs-ref-semantics) – passing by value vs. by reference is decided on a per-function, not per-type, basis.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are passing list by value, thus it is copied, and new elements are added to a local copy inside `add_contact`.

Solution: pass by reference

```
void add_contact(list<Contact>& address_book).
```

Answer (score 1):

Say `void add_contact(list<Contact> & address_book)` to pass the address book by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Pass by reference

```
void add_contact(list<Contact>& address_book).
```