# Error when passing list by reference (C++)

Tags: c++, list, compiler-errors, pass-by-reference

I'm trying to write a subroutine in C++ to take the location of one cell on a square grid and return a list of its' neighbours, so for most cells it will return 4 neighbours, but cells on the edge will only have 3 and in the corner will only have 2. I'm not a very proficient C++ programmer, so I looked up some help on here for passing the list by reference ([C++ pass list as a parameter to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302645/c-pass-list-as-a-parameter-to-a-function)).

I get this error:

```
In function ‘void findNeighbours(int, int, int, int, std::list<int, std::allocator<int> >&)’:

error: invalid conversion from ‘int*’ to ‘int’
```

Here is my code:

```
void findNeighbours(int x, int y, int xSIZE, int ySIZE, list<int>& neighbours){
  int n[2]={x-1,y};
  int e[2]={x,y+1};
  int s[2]={x+1,y};
  int w[2]={x,y-1};
  switch(x){
    case 0: {neighbours.push_back(s);}
    case xSIZE-1: {neighbours.push_back(n);}
    default: {neighbours.push_back(n);neighbours.push_back(s);}
  }
  switch(y){
    case 0: {neighbours.push_back(e);}
    case ySIZE-1: {neighbours.push_back(w);}
    default: {neighbours.push_back(e);neighbours.push_back(w);}
  }
}
```

The line causing the error appears to be this line: 
    case 0: {neighbours.push_back(s);}

but I can't see what I'm doing differently to the example I looked up (linked above).

As I said, I'm not the most proficient C++ coder, so please explain in a simple language as you can. I'm used to using Python so I'm not very good with pointers etc.

Thanks in advance for your help,

FJC

Comment: `push_back(n)` is pushing an *array*, not an `int`. Likewise with `w` and e and s

Comment: you have another error : you need to add a "break" statement between each switch cases, otherwise you will have duplicates neighbors. Also, neighbors accept a list of int, and s[2] is ab array.

Comment: You don't clear the incoming list first, is that ok? Also unless you need to insert/remove in the middle of neighbours later, I suggest vector.

Comment: Maybe you should use a `std::list<std::tuple<int,int>>`, neighbours seem to be pairs of `x,y` coordinate instead of a plain `int`.

Comment: In Python, supposing `n` is an empty list, `n.append((1,2))` would result in `[(1,2)]`, not `[1,2]`. In C++, the compiler catches your error before it happened.

Comment: Simpler (and legal) logic instead of the switches would be: `if ( x != 0 ) neighbours.push_back(s);` `if ( x != xSIZE-1 ) neighbours.push_back(n);`

Comment: @tgmath is there any reason to prefer `tuple` over `pair` ?

Comment: A `vector` is probably a better container choice than `list` here, most operations are faster

Comment: And off on a tangent, you said you want to return a `list`, but make the function void and send in a references. Don't be afraid to have non-void return types in C++.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I don't think so. `pair` seems to be the better choice.

Answer (score 2):

Variable s is defined as an array of two elements

```
int s[2]={x+1,y};
```

While the value type of the list has type int

```
list<int>& neighbours
```

You are trying to push_back the array instead of an object of type int

```
case 0: {neighbours.push_back(s);}
```

I think that in any case the function has no sense at least due to this strange statement

```
case xSIZE-1: {neighbours.push_back(n);}
```

case labels shall be constant expressions.

Answer (score 1):

`s` is array (`int[]`), and `neighbours.push_back` take single `int`! Use in example `neighbours.push_back(s[0])` or `neighbours.push_back(s[1])` or anything, what is `int`.

Answer (score 0):

A naive thing to do is add each neighbour on one line at a time.
We can't use a non constant expression like `xSIZE` in a switch statement.
This makes the code very long and it's crying out to be refactored into something neater, but it's a start.
I'd also return the list rather than pass it in by reference:

```
list<int> findNeighbours(int x, int y, int xSIZE, int ySIZE){
  list<int> neighbours;
  int n[2]={x-1,y};
  int e[2]={x,y+1};
  int s[2]={x+1,y};
  int w[2]={x,y-1};
  if(x == 0)
  {
    neighbours.push_back(s[0]);
    neighbours.push_back(s[1]);
  }
  else if (x == xSIZE-1)
  {
    neighbours.push_back(n[0]);
    neighbours.push_back(n[1]);
  }
  else
  {
    neighbours.push_back(s[0]);
    neighbours.push_back(s[1]);
    neighbours.push_back(n[0]);
    neighbours.push_back(n[1]);
  }

  if(y == 0)
  {
    neighbours.push_back(e[0]);
    neighbours.push_back(e[1]);
  }
  else if (y == ySIZE-1)
  {
    neighbours.push_back(w[0]);
    neighbours.push_back(w[1]);
  }
  else
  {
    neighbours.push_back(e[0]);
    neighbours.push_back(e[1]);
    neighbours.push_back(w[0]);
    neighbours.push_back(w[1]);
  }
  return neighbours;
}
```