# C++ how to pass an STL list to a function

Tags: c++, stl

I wrote the following code in C++. The declaration of the function "change_list" gives an error: 
"incomplete type is not allowed"
and "identifier "list" is undefined". Do you know why? 
I just followed the answers in this post: [C++ pass list as a parameter to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302645/c-pass-list-as-a-parameter-to-a-function)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

typedef struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
} Point;

Point* initPoint(int x, int y) {
    Point* pt = (Point*)malloc(sizeof(Point));
    pt->x = x;
    pt->y = y;
    return pt;
}

void change_list(list<Point*> &mylist){   // ERROR!!!
    mylist.push_back(4);
}

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    list<Point*> c1; // initiating a list
    c1.push_back(initPoint(1, 1));
    c1.push_back(initPoint(2, 2));
    c1.push_back(initPoint(3, 3));

    change_list(c1);

    for (Point* c : c1)
        cout << " " << c->x;
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Try `std::list`.

Comment: `Point* pt = (Point*)malloc(sizeof(Point));` is somewhere between dangerous and wrong - why do you use C style allocations instead of C++ `new`? (Also you have a memory leak since you never free the allocated memory)

Comment: @songyuanyao, thanks. Please write it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is statement `mylist.push_back(4)`, in which you pass an integer whereas `mylist` expects a `Point*`. If you call it like `mylist.push_back(new Point())` it compiles. BTW: maybe you should write `std::list` or place a `using  std::list` somewhere after `#include<list>`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your code :

1. You have used namespace std in main, either use std globally (bad practice) or use std::list.
2. In function change_list, push a valid Point type pointer, you are pushing an integer.

   ```
       void change_list(std::list<Point*> &mylist){   // ERROR!!!
           mylist.push_back(initPoint(8, 8));
       }
   ```